# How to render Sitecore Form using Sitecore Scriban Template

Tags: scriban

I need to render a `Sitecore Form` using the `Sitecore Scriban Template`. I see there is an implementation provided in Stack Exchange using MVC View. But is it possible using `scriban`?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be able to do this with a `VariantComponentField` as a child item of your scriban template item, and using that to add an `Sitecore Form Wrapper` and set the rendering parameters.

You can then run `sc_execute` to execute the component field.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html#sc_execute

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you need to do is to add a `Scriban` template and underneath that, add a `Component` item.

Setup the Form in there (use `MVC Form` as the rendering and set the configuration). Then in the `Scriban` template, use
`{{ sc_execute "[CompoentItemName]" }}` to add that.

It should work.

Comment: Tried as you mentioned. Created a component under scriban template. Set the Rendering as Renderings/System/Forms/MVC Form and also provided the datasource which is the form path. This works fine where the Form is getting rendered properly. However the requirement is to choose any form from the forms collection and it should be dynamic..